# half parskip in koma scrartcl resulting in space at the end of last line before next paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, koma-script, parskip

I wrote some things and wanted to have a part of those left aligned and on the same line some words (or formulas) right aligned. I solved that with `\hfill`.
So sad it is not working on the last line before the end of paragraph when using `parskip=half`. How can I change that?
For clarification a mwe:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german} 
\RequirePackage{mathtools,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\paragraph*{Par one}
\(\displaystyle\iint_{G_x}f\,\mathrm{d}G=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\psi_1\left(x\right)}^{\psi_2\left(x\right)}f\left(x,y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x,\hfill f\text{ stetig auf }G_x\)\\
\hbox{\hskip0pt}\hfill\(\displaystyle\iint_{G_y}f\,\mathrm{d}G=\int_{c}^{d}\int_{\varphi_1\left(y\right)}^{\varphi_2\left(y\right)}f\left(x,y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y,\hfill f\text{ stetig auf }G_y\)
\paragraph*{Par Two}\hfill\(\displaystyle\iiint f\left(x,y,z\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z=\iiint f\left(u,v\right)\left\lvert\det\frac{\partial\left(x,y,z\right)}{\partial\left(u,v,w\right)}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}w
\)
\end{document}
```

And here is the result: Please have a look at the second line of `Par one`.
[image: problem figure]

Comment: `parskip=half` doesn't seem to affect anything like that... the `\hbox{\hskip0pt}\hfill` at the beginning of the second line will make it always be alligned like that. If what you want is to keep things aligned, maybe you should try to wrap into a table or something like that.

Comment: @henrique sorry, you are wrong (please try): When removing `\hbox{\hskip0pt}\hfill` only that left alignment is changed (and of course the space in the middle), but I'm worrying about the right alignment - it should be like in the first line of `Par one`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I though you meant the left alignment. Adding a `\\ ` or `\par` after the last line should correct the right alignment.

Comment: @henrique thanks. But your way inserts the `parskip` length (vertical) - what is not wanted. lockstep found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one of the `parskip` options enabled, `KOMA-Script` will add a space of at least 1em at the end of each paragraph *"[i]n order to avoid a change of paragraph going unnoticed, for instance after a page break"* (manual, p. 50). This is done -- and can be undone -- by changing the `\parfillskip` (rubber) length.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
% \usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german} 
\RequirePackage{mathtools,amsfonts}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}}% instead of 1em plus 1fil
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\paragraph*{Par one}
\(\displaystyle\iint_{G_x}f\,\mathrm{d}G=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\psi_1\left(x\right)}^{\psi_2\left(x\right)}f\left(x,y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x,\hfill f\text{ stetig auf }G_x\)\\
\hbox{\hskip0pt}\hfill\(\displaystyle\iint_{G_y}f\,\mathrm{d}G=\int_{c}^{d}\int_{\varphi_1\left(y\right)}^{\varphi_2\left(y\right)}f\left(x,y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y,\hfill f\text{ stetig auf }G_y\)
\paragraph*{Par Two}\hfill\(\displaystyle\iiint f\left(x,y,z\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z=\iiint f\left(u,v\right)\left\lvert\det\frac{\partial\left(x,y,z\right)}{\partial\left(u,v,w\right)}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}w
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There exist even an KOMA-option:`parskip=half-` instead of `parskip=half`. Now, the last line of an paragraph can use the full textwidth.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this behavior for just one paragraph? Bonus points for a solution that does it automatically whenever `\fill` is used :)